# Iterating through each column of each workbook in C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, excel-interop

Alright, so this is my first venture into C#, and I kind of have an idea of where I need to go, but I wanted to make sure I'm doing this right. The situation is I have a group of excel workbooks (each only one worksheet) and I want to use a foreach loop to copy each column into a new excel sheet.

My problem is setting up the foreach loop. I think I need to use two, like this:

```
foreach (Excel.Workbook in Excel.Application) {
    foreach (range column{} in Excel.Workbook) {}
}
```

Am I totally off or on the right track?

Comment: The short answer is yes, you'll need 2 foreach loops.  Have you had a look at the OpenXml sdk? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc822064.aspx
When you say "each column" - do you mean each column *header* or each column of data (i.e. all rows in that col)?

Comment: The overall goal is to read the header each column, and then based on it's content paste it into a new excel sheet in a specific column. For example, column A in sheet1 has a header of x, B has a header of Y. Column A of sheet2 has a header of Y and column B has X. The two columns with x will be pasted into a new document, in the same column. I know I'm going to need a switch for that.